# Use response value in child window

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, childwindow

I am having difficulty getting to grips with how Silverlight uses asynchronous responses from a web service. I have declared-

```
public partial class Users : Page
{
    public string PID;
```

and then use-

```
 if
 {
 WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();
 string profile = System.Convert.ToString(((ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem).Content);
 client.pidReturnCompleted += new EventHandler<pidReturnCompletedEventArgs>(client_pidReturnCompleted);
 client.pidReturnAsync(USERID, profile);
 }
 Else
 {

 KeyWords keywords = new KeyWords();

 keywords.textBox3.Text = PID;
 keywords.Show();
```

Where PID-

```
void client_pidReturnCompleted(object sender, pidReturnCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        PID = e.Result;
    }
```

I then need to use this PID in the `Initialise Component` section of the Keywords child window, however when the window loads, it does not get the textBox.Text (the PID value) in time, and says it is null. How can I use the PID in the Initialise Component stage? So in the Keywords window-

```
public KeyWords()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(KeyWords_Loaded);

        WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();
        client.userKeywordsCompleted += new EventHandler<userKeywordsCompletedEventArgs>(client_userKeywordsCompleted);
        client.userKeywordsAsync(PID);

    }
```

Where- `Public Int PID = textBox3.Text //this is where the value from the previous window is passed in.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it by creating a Keywords_Loaded void. I was then able to use the values passed in from the previous form.